# Improving performance of double for loops

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

I'm working on an algorithm for recommendations as restaurants to the client. These recommendations are based on a few filters, but mostly by comparing reviews people have left on restaurants. (I'll spare you the details).

For calculating a pearson correlation (A number which determines how well users fit with eachother) I have to check where users have left a review on the same restaurant. To increase the amount of matches, I've included a match on the price range of the subjects. I'll try to explain, here is my Restaurant class:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int PriceRange { get; set; }
}
```

This is a simplified version, but it's enough for my example. A pricerange can be an integer of 1-5 which determines how expensive the restaurant is.

Here's the for loop I'm using to check if they left reviews on the same restaurant or a review on a restaurant with the same pricerange.

```
//List<Review> user1Reviews is a list of all reviews from the first user
//List<Review> user2Reviews is a list of all reviews from the second user
Dictionary<Review, Review> shared_items = new Dictionary<Review, Review>();
    foreach (var review1 in user1Reviews)
        foreach (var review2 in user2Reviews)
            if (review1.Restaurant.Id == review2.Restaurant.Id || 
                review1.Restaurant.PriceRange == review2.Restaurant.PriceRange)
                if (!shared_items.ContainsKey(review1))
                    shared_items.Add(review1, review2);
```

Now here's my actual problem. You can see I'm looping the second list for each review the first user has left. Is there a way to improve the performance of these loops? I have tried using a hashset and the .contains() function, but I need to include more criteria (I.e. the price range). I couldn't figure out how to include that in a hashset.

I hope it's not too confusing, and thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit: After testing both linq and the for loops I have concluded that the for loops is twice as fast as using linq. Thanks for your help!**

Comment: You don't have a double loop. Your code asks  "How do I match reviews by restaurant or price range"? Which can be done without loops, eg with a LINQ Join and even parallelized.

Comment: Won't this just match a review from user 1 with the first review from user 2 that has the same price instead of all restaurants with the same price (what's worse is that it will end up taking the price match if it finds one before a possible id match which seems like the one you'd prefer having).

Comment: @juharr yes, this is the issue I've been struggling with for a long time. It's hard to determine which reviews to match. The problem with only matching on restaurant ids is that the amount of matches can be too small. We have been discussing this a lot, but I honestly don't know how to improve this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to calculate? Find all related `user2` reviews or just a random one? Explain the problem, not the (buggy) implementation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't even thought about this, I'll try it out! Thanks!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To calculate a pearson correlation, you need to compare several reviews which match on something per 2 users. The formula then compares each matched review on rating and then returns a number which indicates how related they are (I.e. they rated each restaurant the same)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to match on type of restaurant (Mexican, American, French) instead of on price?  Just because two restaurants share a similar price doesn't really make them very similar.

Comment: @juharr yes, this would probably be the best. I'll discuss this more with my team. But coming back on topic, do you have any ideas on improving the performance of this function?

Comment: Well the first thing would be to do a `break` inside that `if` so you can stop looping the inner loop.  That also would allow you to get rid of the check to see if `review1` is already in the dictionary (assuming that you don't have duplicates in your sequence).

Comment: @Bas what about building 2 hashmaps from `user2Reviews`, one for `Id` and one for `PriceRange` and having only one loop, where you would use `hashmapId.ContainsKey(review1.Restaurant.Id) || hashmapPriceRange.ContainsKey(review1.Restaurant.PriceRange)` condition instead? Should be faster.

Comment: I'll test all of your suggestions and benchmark them, thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing your inner loop by a Linq query using the criteria of the outer loop:

```
foreach (var review1 in user1Reviews)
{
    var review2 = user2Reviews.FirstOrDefault(r2 => r2.Restaurant.Id == review1.Restaurant.Id ||
                                            r2.Restaurant.PriceRange == review1.Restaurant.PriceRange);
    if (review2 != null)
    {
        if (!shared_items.ContainsKey(review1))
            shared_items.Add(review1, review2);
    }
}
```

If there are multiple matches you should use `Where` and deal with the potential list of results.

I'm not sure it would be any quicker though as you still have to check all the user2 reviews against the user1 reviews.

Hoever, if you wrote a custom comparer for your restaurant class you could use this overload of [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx) to return you the common reviews:

```
var commonReviews = user1Reviews.Intersect(user2Reviews, new RestaurantComparer());
```

Where RestaurantComparer looks something like this:

```
// Custom comparer for the Restaurant class
class RestaurantComparer : IEqualityComparer<Restaurant>
{
    // Products are equal if their ids and price ranges are equal.
    public bool Equals(Restaurant x, Restaurant y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the properties are equal.
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.PriceRange == y.PriceRange;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Id field.
        int hashId product.Id.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field.
        int hashPriceRange = product.PriceRange.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashId ^ hashPriceRange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where` since the OP is just going to add the first match only.

Comment: When I tried to implement this, it's telling me that I can't convert from list to parallelquery. Is there something I need to change?

Comment: This one: var commonReviews = user1Reviews.Intersect(user2Reviews, new RestaurantComparer()); It generates the error on both lists

Comment: @Bas - odd. But you haven't shown how `user1Reviews` and `user2Reviews` are generated. Are they the results of a ParallelQuery? If so you'll need to convert them to lists before using `Intersect`.

Comment: They are lists coming from parameters in the function. I haven't used a ParallelQuery anywhere in my query.

Comment: @Bas - even odder. I can't see why it would give that error then.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a fast way to locate a review by `Id` **or** `PriceRange`. Normally you would use fast hash based lookup structure like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for a single key, or composite key if the match operation was **and**. Unfortunately your is **or**, so the `Dictionary` doesn't work.

Well, not really. Single dictionary does not work, but you can use two dictionaries, and since the dictionary lookup is O(1), the operation will still be O(N) (rather than O(N * M) as with inner loop / naïve LINQ).

Since the keys are not unique, instead of dictionaries you can use [lookups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx), keeping the same efficiency:

```
var lookup1 = user2Reviews.ToLookup(r => r.Restaurant.Id);
var lookup2 = user2Reviews.ToLookup(r => r.Restaurant.PriceRange);
foreach (var review1 in user1Reviews)
{
    var review2 = lookup1[review.Restaurant.Id].FirstOrDefault() ??
                  lookup2[review.Restaurant.PriceRange].FirstOrDefault();
    if (review2 != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and it's actually a lot slower than using the for loops. The for loops took (From a random test) 3004 ticks and your function took 18608 ticks. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if the function is really slow, I just wanted to let you know!

Comment: Hmm, this is the first time I'm hearing that hash lookup is slower than linear search. How many items contains `userReviews2`? i.e. in your test, if N=user1Reviews.Count, M=user2Reviews.Count, N = ? and M = ?

Comment: Both lists consist of 6 reviews. I'm currently just testing this on a small scale

Comment: If both list contains only 6 review, it won't matters much how you matches items as you would only have 6 * 6  = 36 pairs... and many could be rejected (not the same restaurant nor the same price range). Another idea might be to sort item by restaurant id and then price range. That way, you can more easily adjust the number of items you use for comparison depending on how much review you get...

Comment: Yeah, counting ticks doesn't make sense. Try 1000 by 1000 and then you'll see the difference.